# Canvas drawImage() : How to place a large dimension image into a small canvas?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

In a canvas by 960*960 dimension, how can I draw an image of larger dimension without cropping the image. Auto re-size for images possible in canvas ?

Comment: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-drawimage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `drawImage` method to scale the image when you draw it. There are 3 forms of `drawImage`:

```
drawImage(image, destX, destY)
drawImage(image, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight)
drawImage(image, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight)
```

You probably want the second one. If you don't want to preserve aspect ratio, this will work:

```
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 960, 960)
```

If you do need to preserve the aspect ratio, you can do some computation to figure out how much you need to scale it to "just fit" in the canvas.